# Visual Studio 2015 An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, exception

I am using a 64bit Win8.1 and Visual Studio 2015. I have a simple bit of code on VB windows form to query an access database on my machine. The Code (snippet) is

```
    cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
    "Data Source=C:\Users\XXX\Documents\XXXX.accdb"

    cn.Open(strConnection)
    rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
```

It has been working fine until I did a repair on my office professional plus 2016 32bit software on my machine. Now when it gets to the cn.execute part it throws up the following error below

I have reinstalled the Microsoft Access Database engine I had installed on my machine. Any advice?

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147217904
  HResult=-2147217904
  Message=No value given for one or more required parameters.
  Source=Microsoft Access Database Engine
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.LateGet(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
       at StaffDB.Form1.SearchBtn1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\StaffDB\StaffDB\Form1.vb:line 99
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at StaffDB.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```